# Trying to correct a file name in Windows Registry

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

While researching a Powershell security problem, I found several creative suggestions on SO.
But before I could try them out, I created my own problem in the forbidden Windows Registry.
By dumb mistake I partly erased a folder name, which I have been unable to correct.
Googled a slew of keyword combos that all led to Powershell USES, not to folder NAMES.
So here is my embarrassing first SO forum question:

In HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, Powershell has five folders, appearing in this order:

```
MicrosoftPowerShellConsole1
MicrosoftPowerShell**?Name?**
MicrosoftPowerShellModule1
MicrosoftPowerShellScript1
MicrosoftPowerShellXMLData1
```

Can somebody suggest the best search keywords to use, or even better, the missing ?filename?
Thank you very much.
John

Comment: You might be able to use Windows System Restore to revert to a previous restore point before you deleted the registry entries.

Comment: So you **don't** know the file name?

Comment: Probably `Microsoft.PowerShellData.1`, but did you just erased part of the Key's name (a registry has **keys** they just look like folders in regedit) or did you also delete the values and subkeys inside? I would use @Daniel 's advice and use System Restore first instead of trying to mend it.. P.S. You left out the dots in the key names...

Comment: Thankyou very much Theo and Daniel. for suggestion to use System Restore. I already tried that in vain with different restore points, antivirus disabled, safe mode and several other suggestions from googling.

Comment: So I gave up on that, and repaired the filename with Theo's help. No, I did not erase any of the folder contents. I left out the dots in the key names only because SO called me out for I think "programming language" which I did not fully understand yet? Going into the registry in the first place was to solve a problem I had and still have wiith Powershell. I think SO will require that to be a whole new post, where I will indeed need to quote "programming language"?  Thanks again.